# Get last record from group by cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables : User and LoginLogs and User and LoginLog have 'has Many' relationships.
I have to get last login of user from the LoginLog table. I have to query the details of last login user using group by.
Here is the Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `login_logs` 
AS `LoginLog` 
LEFT JOIN `users` 
AS `User` 
ON (`LoginLog`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `LoginLog`.`user_id` 
ORDER BY `LoginLog`.`login_datetime` DESC LIMIT 20
```

This Query returns first login record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are using limit 20 ? Use limit 0,1 For  find  first record order  by  login_datetime DESC

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `login_logs` 
AS `LoginLog` 
LEFT JOIN `users` 
AS `User` 
ON (`LoginLog`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1  ORDER BY `LoginLog`.`login_datetime` DESC LIMIT 0 ,1
```

Answer (score -1):

In pseudocode :

```
 SELECT * FROM LoginLog 
 WHERE MAX(LoginLog.primary_id) AND user.id = loginLog.userId
```

assuming that there is auto increment PK column in LoginLog

do not forget to index userId columns to get better performance

Comment: this gives `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`